# Could you explain this kind of future? "Clare wants to be a doctor when she is older."

Tags: sentence-structure, future-tense

Could you explain this kind of future, please?

> Clare wants to be a doctor when she is older

Why isn't there are any use of *will* or *going to*?

Comment: It is not about the future, just a current desire. Tomorrow she might want to be something else.

Comment: Because English has no future tense, it has to rely on other ways to talk about the future. In your example, the temporal adjunct "when she is older" clearly indicates that we are talking about some possible event in the future.

Comment: @BillJ English has no future tense, are you high?

Comment: @Cardinal What?

Comment: @BillJ I say, Are you Ok? Why you think English has no future **tense**!

Comment: @Cardinal. English has no future tense because our verbs have no future tense inflections. Here's a link to University College London's grammar website that may help you: [link](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/tense.htm)

Comment: @BillJ I don't know if all of academia has agreed that there's no future tense. Rather, it differs from other languages in that it relies on the auxiliary _will_ or _shall_. All that one needs is a demonstration of futurity. In this case, the auxiliary _is_ the modification (which is what inflection is.) Basically, this is less black and white and people could easily call it the future tense. Or future perfect if you use _will have._

Comment: Mostly, yes. Syntactically, the modal auxiliary verb "will" has two tenses: present and preterite. Semantically, it is used to make reference to future time (about 80% of its occurrences, I believe). But "will" belongs grammatically and semantically with the auxiliaries that mark mood, not tense. It would be utterly wrong to perpetuate the myth that English has a future tense. And what would it achieve anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are from Peru, I expect you are wondering why the sentence is not constructed the way it is in Spanish.

> *Clare quiere ser una doctora cuando sea grande.*

which in English we say as...

> Clare *wants* to be a doctor when she is older.

The verb in the first clause indicates a desire at the present moment, and is the same as in Spanish.

However, English does not have a subjunctive to use with time words.

> *...cuando **sea** grande*

In [clauses with time words](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-time-clauses-and-if-clauses) (when, until, after) we usually use the present tense to talk about the future.

ex.

> We will talk about it *when* I come home.
>
> Don't do anything *until* we talk.
>
> You can make a decision *after* we discuss it.

It follows the same pattern as *if* and *unless* clauses when talking about the future.

> I will take care of it *if* you agree.
>
> I won't buy it *unless* you like it.

*Will* is not usually used with time words or *if*.

"Going to" is usually used to express intention, or a prediction.

> This weekend I'm *going to* the beach.
>
> It looks like it is *going* to rain.

We could also say...

> Clare is going to be a Doctor when she is older.

...to indicate her intention. Or we could also say...

> Clare would like to be a Doctor when she is older.

...to indicate her current desire for the future, but the clauses with time words stay the same as the above examples.

Comment: I have edited this answer to include  a more detailed explanation of why I answered it the way I did the first time round for the benefit of _non-Spanish_ speakers. I used to get this question all the time when I taught EFL to native Spanish speakers, and as the OP accepted the answer, I am pretty sure it was the intent of his original question.

Comment: Thanks @gandalf for make your response even more detailed. It was very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it was answered in the comments but I'll give you a clearer example here.

> Clare wants to be a doctor when she is older.

This is asserting Clare's current desire.

> Clare will want to be a doctor when she is older.

This is asserting that in the future Clare will have this desire.